# How to Connect to Remote SQL Server Database Over Internet Using Public Static IP and Port Number?

Tags: sql-server, tcp, remote-connection

I want to connect to my remote SQL Server over a different network, namely the internet.

Even though my connection with Local IP is successful, I get connection error with Public IP (ex: 88.240.xxx.xxx).

I followed the steps below.

1. I enabled SQL Server and Windows authentication modes
2. I created a user
3. I have enabled SQL Server to allow remote connections
4. TCP/IP is enabled in SQL Server Configuration
5. I set the TCP/IP>>TCPAll field to 1433
6. I restarted SQL Server
7. I added a rule for TCP and UDP in Windows Firewall
8. I did port forwarding from the modem settings

After these steps, when I type local ip in the server name field, the connection is successful, but my connection with the public ip is lost.
If anyone knows a way around this can help?

Error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

[Allowing Remote Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxrSl.png)

[SQL Server authentication mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGebs.png)

[SQL Server Configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vICgB.png)

[Port Forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfUce.png)

Comment: Based on the error message the client is trying to use the named pipes provider instead of TCP. What happens if you type `ipAddress,1433` into SSMS on the remote client?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for your answer. In SSMS, I wrote ip, port number in the server name field.  But still the connection failed.For example: I wrote 192.168.1.51, 1433.

Comment: Possibly there's some confusion here over what Port Forwarding does. This is normally something to open a port on your router's public IP to connect to a service inside your own local area network. If your remote SQL Server is accessible on 88.240.xxx.xxx then you should just be using 88.240.xxx.xxx,1433 in SSMS.

Comment: I'm sorry, in my previous comment I wrote that I got an error by showing my connection to my local network as an example. When I use only the public ip 88.240.xxx.xxx,1433 in SSMS, my connection fails.
I do not have any problems with my connection with local ip.

Comment: Exposing a database server to the internet is generally a [bad idea](https://serverfault.com/questions/19945/the-wisdom-of-exposing-a-database-server-on-the-internet) - especially if you do not have the networking and security expertise to understand how to do it and how to mitigate the risks.